# Binary search when terminating condition is `left < right`, step update is `left = mid +1, right = mid`

Tags: python, algorithm

I was reading the [Binary Search Template II in leetcode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/126/template-ii/937/):

> It is used to search for an element or condition which requires *accessing the current index and its immediate right neighbor's index* in the array.
>
> ```
> def binarySearch(nums, target):
>     """
>     :type nums: List[int]
>     :type target: int
>     :rtype: int
>     """
>     if len(nums) == 0:
>         return -1
>
>     left, right = 0, len(nums)
>     while left < right:
>         mid = (left + right) // 2
>         if nums[mid] == target:
>             return mid
>         elif nums[mid] < target:
>             left = mid + 1
>         else:
>             right = mid
>
>     # Post-processing:
>     # End Condition: left == right
>     if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
>         return left
>     return -1
> ```

I seems to me that the extra condition `and nums[left] == target` is unnecessary.

When changing:

```
if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
```

to just:

```
if left != len(nums):
```

...it works perfectly:

```
def binarySearch(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left == right
    if left != len(nums):
        return left
    return -1
```

Tests:

```
In [4]: nums = list(range(100))             

In [5]: binarySearch(nums, 55)              
Out[5]: 55

In [6]: binarySearch(nums, 101)             
Out[6]: -1

In [7]: binarySearch(nums, 38)              
Out[7]: 38
```

What's the reason `nums[left] == target` should be added?

Leetcode's summary on the template (for reference if you could not open its link):

> #### Key Attributes:
>
> - An advanced way to implement Binary Search.
> - Search Condition needs to access element's immediate right neighbor
> - Use element's right neighbor to determine if condition is met and decide whether to go left or right
> - Gurantees [sic] Search Space is at least 2 in size at each step
> - Post-processing required. Loop/Recursion ends when you have 1 element left. Need to assess if the remaining element meets the
>     condition.
>
> #### Distinguishing Syntax:
>
> - Initial Condition: `left = 0, right = length`
> - Termination: `left == right`
> - Searching Left: `right = mid`
> - Searching Right: `left = mid+1`

Comment: Test with `nums = [9]` and `binarySearch(nums, 2)`. You need the last condition to ensure that you actually found the target element.

Comment: It works `In [19]: binarySearch(list(range(10)), 2)   
Out[19]: 2

In [20]: binarySearch(list(range(9)), 2)    
Out[20]: 2
`  @ChrisHappy

Comment: Sorry, the list should not be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`. It should just be `9`. Rephrased, the binary_search algorithm fails when the element is not in the array **and** it is not bigger than the biggest element and not smaller than the smallest element.

Comment: So, could be just delete the line ` if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:`

Answer (score 2):

In contrast with canonical version of binary search where the loop terminates as soon as `lo > hi` is met, in this case the loop terminates when `lo == hi`. But since the element `nums[lo]` (which is also `nums[hi]`) has to be inspected as well, the additional check is added after the loop.

It is guaranteed that the loop terminates only and only when `lo == hi`, because moving left includes `mid` element in the future search (`else:  right = mid`) while in canonical version, `mid` element is excluded from the future search in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Test with `nums = [9]` and `binarySearch(nums, 2)`. Assuming I understand the code properly, `binary_search` would return `0` as the "index" of the found item.

You need the last condition to ensure that **you actually found the target element**.

Otherwise, you're just finding a index for the item closest to the target in the array.

One more example:

```
IN nums = [1, 3, 4]

IN binary_search(nums, 2)
OUT 2 /* When 2 isn't in the array */
```

Comment: example cannot be a formal indication of the necessity of that check (and especially that "roughly" thing)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you change `if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:` to `if left != len(nums):`
it **seems** to work fine because your tests are being made with `nums = list(range(100))` which generates the integer sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., 99`, as such, every index of `nums` is the same as its element, that is `nums[i] == i`. Without `nums[left] == target` you're actually returning the closest index to the index of your `target` element, and since with your test every index coincides with its element then it appears to give correct results but **it's wrong**. The `nums[left] == target` is the terminating condition that ensures that you actually found your `target` element in `nums`.