# A logic error within a quick binary search solution to find square root but fail to capure with enormous testings

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I have such a binary search to find square root of a positive integer

```
In [95]: find_square_root??                         
Signature: find_square_root(x)
Docstring: <no docstring>
Source:   
def find_square_root(x):
    if x < 2:
        return x

    lo = 0
    hi = x

    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2 #

        if mid ** 2 == x:
            lo = mid
            return lo
        if mid ** 2 < x:
            lo = mid + 1
        if mid ** 2 > x:
            hi = mid
        print(f"mid={mid}, lo={lo}, hi={hi}")

    return lo -1
File:      /tmp/ipython_edit_um5dfgck/ipython_edit_sdk9u57g.py
Type:      function
```

I tested up to  50**5 cases which works  properly

```
for i in range(50, 50**5):
    res = find_square_root(i**2)
    assert res == i, f"res={res}, i={i}"
```

However, there exist a logic bug there roughly.

Suppose only two numbers left finally, lo and hi which are adjacent to each other surely and they are not tested yet.
According to the algorithms, `mid = (lo + hi) // 2`, since it floor division, mid is actually equals to lo, so one of the left two number is tested,
additionally `if mid ** 2 > x:`, then hi = mid = lo,
this way, the function quit safely.

However, if `if mid ** 2 < x:`, then `lo = mid + 1` which means lo = hi and the loop quit with `hi` left untested.
It seems like a solid logic bug.

but I am not sure because it passed mass of testings.

Comment: testing up to `50**50` would take a supercomputer quite some time, so how did you do it since the last question you asked about the same function 40 minutes ago?

Comment: You should not add a conclusion to your question based on the answer(s). The purpose of a question is that it remains a question. Answers should remain in the answer section. That is how this site works.

Comment: okay, I got the idea. @trincot

Comment: @Algebra: if you want to show an answer that builds upon another answer, you are entitled to add an answer below. Just attribute the work to the relevant authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if mid ** 2 < x:, then lo = mid + 1 which means lo = hi and the loop quit with hi left untested.
>   It seems like a solid logic bug.

There is no bug here. `hi` is not left untested, as `hi` is the value that `mid` had in a previous iteration, when `hi = mid` was executed, and so it was already tested there.

If there was never such previous iteration where `hi` was modified, then this means `hi` equals `x`, and that in each iteration `mid ** 2 < x` is true, until and including when `mid == x - 2` (which would assign `li = x - 1`). But this can only happen when `x < 4`. In those few cases the solution is 1. As we know `x > 1` after the first `if`, we have `hi > 1`, so no problem for those cases either. You could even change the first `if` to `if x < 4`...

Comment: I feel this the right answer,  need a while to think thoroughly, thank you. I assured that  I am not alone stuck on the problem, see my question on Leetcode's official solution to such a template. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515399/binary-search-when-terminating-condition-is-left-right-step-update-is-left

Comment: Leetcode official template does not think very clearly on the problem.

Comment: thank you very much for editing the linked question, I 'd prefer to  keep your name of editing to that question and move the edited question here. so in that question, just do remove the unnecessary  lines of ` if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:`

Comment: You can edit this question yourself. Copy whatever you like from that linked question into this one. It's yours ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The way to think about it is that `hi` is one past the end of the range you're searching. So the numbers being searched are the range `lo` to `hi-1`, and there is never any need to test `hi`. Once `lo == hi`, the range is empty so the number wasn't found, and there is no need to continue testing. So there is no logic error in this code.

Comment: ty, I am considering that there is no slicing, slicing is half close half open; is it also the inferior machaniam python do (lo +hi)/2 ? hi is excluded?

Comment: If you are referring to list slicing, there is no list here. And even if there was, slicing would copy the data and make things slow. I don't know what you mean by "inferior mechanism". The choice to make the range [lo,hi) is that of the algorithm writer and has nothing to do with python's slicing.

Comment: I should wrap my mind around for a while, one thing is that hi is not within a range function.