# Binary Search Template Leetcode, The meaning of it?

Tags: binary-search

[I Found a Binary Search Template here in leetcode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/126/template-ii/937/)

```
def binarySearch(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left == right
    if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
        return left
    return -1
```

They say that *"Template #2 is an advanced form of Binary Search. It is used to search for an element or condition which requires accessing the current index and its immediate right neighbor's index in the array."*

I am struggling to understand what the information above means. In a usual binary search right would be

```
right = len(nums) - 1 # before while loop

right = mid - 1 # inside while loop
```

and the while loop would be

```
while left <= right:
```

Comment: see my answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515399/binary-search-when-terminating-condition-is-left-right-step-update-is-left/58515580#58515580

Comment: I understood a lot but also can you tell me why "right = length" is used on the initialization of right

Comment: not sure why `right` is initialized to `length` instead of `lengh-1`. there is no advantage of doing that. moreover, if array consists of a single element, `right = length` will make the loop run one unnecessary iteration, while `right = length-1` will not enter the loop and will pass directly to the `left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target` check

Comment: I have tested some input and lets say that u are returning leftPointer, then lets say u have [1,2,4] if u are looking for 5, right = len(nums) version gives you index 3 but the len(nums) - 1 version gives you index 2

Comment: No difference. In case of `right = len(nums)`, the loop will stop as soon as `left=3` and `right=3`. The `if` check will fail on `left != len(nums)` so `-1` is returned. In case of `right = len(nums)-1`, the loop will stop as soon as `left=2` and `right=2`. The `if` check will fail on `nums[left] == target` so `-1` is returned again

Comment: yea but consider the sentence "lets say that u are returning leftPointer"

Comment: you mean this block? - `if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target: return left`. The value of leftPointer is not returned if both conditions are not satisfied. maybe you are talking about some other variation of bin.search

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a binary search on an array.
Lets say the array has 100 elements.

```
#    left, right = 0, len(nums)
left = 0, right = 99
#        mid = (left + right) // 2
mid = 49

#        elif nums[mid] < target:
We need to move right.
#            left = mid + 1
left = 50 and right = 99
#        else:
We need to move left.
#            right = mid
Left = 0, right = 49
```

Comment: at the first snippet, mid should be 50 not 49